# Keydown Not Triggered Only on Button w/ "contenteditable" Tag

Tags: jquery, contenteditable

I am using the `contenteditable="true"` tag to make the content in certain tags editable. I can successfully edit the content in any element with that tag, but the problem arises when I try to detect the `keydown` event with jQuery.

[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nN6jC/1/)

Note that "Hello World", in a paragraph element, is editable. The button text "I'm a Button" is also editable, inside a button element.

When you type in the paragraph element, `keypresses` is incremented for each key pressed. However, when you type in the button element, `keypresses` is **NOT** incremented. This is my problem. Apparently, the `keydown` event is not being detected inside the button element, even though it is being detected inside the paragraph element.

To demonstrate that this is not a problem with the way the JS is written, clicking either paragraph or button element will increment the `clicks` counter.

So my question is, why isn't the `keydown` event being detected inside the button element, and what can I do to detect it?

Comment: Your fiddle works in IE10 and Firefox23, but does not in Chrome 28.0.1500.95 - a webkit issue, I guess. Indeed, `ontenteditable="true"` is not quite mature yet.

Comment: Ah yes, forgot to test with other browsers. Hmm, any idea of a possible fix for Chrome?

Comment: No ideas right out of head.. If you could reproduce it with pure javascript (no jQuery), you might report it to Google as a bug. Otherwise, it'd be a jQuery issue.

Comment: OK thanks, I was able to replicate it in JS and will be submitting a bug report. Here's the link in case you are interested http://jsfiddle.net/bDnAs/2/.

Comment: A bug indeed - well done!

Comment: I don't think it's just contenteditable's fault really: I imagine it's more that `<button>` elements don't generate key events in Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this work-around?

**JSFiddle** : http://jsfiddle.net/vA74w/

Putting button content in a `span` with `contenteditable=true`

**HTML**

```
<button>&nbsp;<span contenteditable='true'>I'm a Button</span>&nbsp;</button>
```

`&nbsp;` will not allow user to delete the button.

Need to trim `&nbsp;` and `span` tags from button text after completing the edit.

Comment: Great, nice and simple, great solution. Thanks!